# What are the differences between $, @, % in Perl variable declaration?

Tags: perl, syntax, declaration

Example:

```
my $some_variable;
my @some_variable;
my %some_variable;
```

I know, `@` seems to be for array, `$` for primitive, is it totally right?
What is `%` for?

Comment: You could lookup `sigil` on google.

Comment: This can't possibly NOT be a duplicate

Comment: some people obviously disagree, please help delete this question

Comment: @dvk: did you mean cannot delete? or just close it plz

Comment: `%` is for hashes. [Refer Here](http://perlmaven.com/perl-hashes)

Answer (score 45):

One of the nice things about Perl is that it comes with a built in manual. Type in the following command:

```
perldoc perlintro
```

and take a look at the section *Perl variable types*. You can also see this on line with the [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types) section on Perl variables.

A quick overview:

- **$foo** is a *scalar* variable. It can hold a single value which can be a string, numeric, etc.
- **@foo** is an *array*. Arrays can hold multiple values. You can access these values using an index. For example **$foo[0]** is the first element of the array and **$foo[1]** is the second element of the array, etc. (Arrays usually start with zero).
- **%foo** is a *hash*, this is like an array because it can hold more than one value, but hashes are keyed arrays. For example, I have a password hash called **%password**. This is keyed by the user name and the values are the user's password. For example:

  $password{Fred} = "swordfish";
  $password{Betty} = "secret";

  $user = "Fred";
  print "The Password for user $user is $password{$user}\n";  #Prints out Swordfish
  $user = "Betty";
  print "The Password for user $user is $password{$user}\n";  #Prints out secret

Note that when you refer to a single value in a *hash* or *array*, you use the dollar sign. It's a little confusing for beginners.

I would recommend that you get the *Llama Book*. The *Llama Book* is [Learning Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001322) and is an excellent introduction to the language.

Comment: What about a @ before a $?  
In the example below - $baseball_team_ids is passed to a subroutine then referenced in a new variable creation. 

my $total_ids = scalar(@$baseball_teamIDs);

Answer (score 24):

`$` is for scalars, `@` is for arrays, and `%` is for hashes. See the [Variable Types](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types) section of the docs for more information.

Answer (score 14):

`$` is scalar, `@` is array, and `%` is hash.

Comment: yeah, but why $_ and @_ are the same for containing pass-in parameters to a funcction? or i'm wrong?

Comment: @nicola, Array and hash elements use "$". `$_[0]` is the first element of `@_`. Both are unrelasted to `$_`.

Comment: @nicola => `@_` is an array containing all of the arguments passed to a function.  `$_` is a scalar containing the current item being worked with in situations like `for (@array) {...}`.  `$_` has nothing to do with `@_`.  Where you are likely getting confused is that to access an individual element of the argument list, you would write `$_[0]`, which accesses the first element.  Here the sigil changes to `$` to denote that you are accessing a scalar, however the trailing `[0]` tells perl that it is accessing a scalar element of the array in `_` or in other words, `@_`.

Answer (score 6):

$var denotes a single-valued scalar variable 
@var denotes an array 
%var denotes an associative array or hash (they are both the same)