# Problems with Arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am new to Perl and having some difficulty with arrays in Perl. Can somebody will explain to me as to why I am not able to print the value of an array in the script below.

```
$sum=();
$min = 999;
$LogEntry = '';
foreach $item (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
{
  $min = $item if $min > $item;
  if ($LogEntry eq '') {
    push(@sum,"1"); }
    print "debugging the IF condition\n";
}
print "Array is: $sum\n";
print "Min = $min\n";
```

The output I get is:

```
debugging the IF condition
debugging the IF condition
debugging the IF condition
debugging the IF condition
debugging the IF condition
Array is:
Min = 1
```

Shouldn't I get `Array is: 1 1 1 1 1` (5 times).
Can somebody please help?
Thanks.

Comment: There must be some code missing, there is nothing that would cause $logEntry to change from an empty string and the debugging message will always be printed as it is outside the if braces.

Answer (score 7):

You need two things:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

at which point the bug in your code (`$sum` instead of `@sum`) should become obvious...

Comment: Regardless of fixing this problem specifically, using strict and warnings like Alnitak says should pretty much be second nature. Always do it.

Answer (score 6):

$sum is not the same variable as @sum.

In this case you would benefit from starting your script with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

[Strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) forces you to declare all variables, and warnings gives warnings..

In the meantime, change the first line to:

```
@sum = ();
```

and the second-to-last line to:

```
print "Array is: " . join (', ', @sum) . "\n";
```

See [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html).

Comment: It has to be `my @sum=();` with strict.

Answer (score 6):

As others have noted, you need to understand the way Perl uses sigils (`$`, `@`, `%`) to denote data structures and the access of the data in them.

You are using a scalar sigil (`$`), which will simply try to access a scalar variable named `$sum`, that has nothing to do with a completely distinct array variable named `@sum` - and you obviously want the latter.

What confuses you is likely the fact that, once the array variable `@sum` exists, you can access individual values in the array using `$sum[0]` syntax, but here the sigil+braces (`$[]`) act as a "unified" syntactic constract.

---

The first thing you need to do (after using strict and warnings) is to read the following documentation on sigils in Perl (aside from good Perl book):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2732643/119280 - brian d. foy's excellent summary
- The rest of the answers to the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2731542/119280)
- This SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5554495/119280)

---

The best summary I can give you on the syntax of accessing data structures in Perl is (quoting from my older comment)

- **the sigil represents the amount of data from the data structure that you are retrieving (`$` of 1 element, `@` for a list of elements, `%` for entire hash)**
- **whereas the brace style represent what your data structure is (square for array, curly for hash).**

  As a special case, when there are NO braces, the sigil will represent BOTH the amount of data, as well as what the data structure is.

---

Please note that in your specific case, it's the last bullet point that matters. Since you're referring to the array as a whole, you won't have braces, and therefore the sigil will represent the data structure type - since it's an array, you must use the `@` sigil.

Answer (score 3):

You `push` the values into the array `@sum`, then finish up by printing the scalar `$sum`.  `@sum` and `$sum` are two *completely independent* variables.  If you `print "@sum\n"` instead, you should get the output "11111".

Answer (score 2):

```
print "Array is: $sum\n";
```

will print a non-existent scalar variable called $sum, not the array @sum and not the first item of the array.

If you 'use strict' it will flag the user of un-initialized variables like this.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitly add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to your script. That would have complained about the `print "Array is: $sum\n";` line (among others).
And you initialize an array with `my @sum=();` not with `my $sum=();`

Answer (score 1):

Like CFL_Jeff mentions, you can't just do a quick print. Instead, do something like:

```
print "Array is ".join(', ',@array);
```

Comment: Actually, you can interpolate an array into the string: `print "Arr: @array\n";`. Won't look as pretty by default, of course

Comment: Not as pretty, but still worth noting - thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Still would like to add some details to this picture. )

See, Perl is well-known as a Very High Level Language. And this is not just because you can replace `(1,2,3,4,5)` with `(1..5)` and get the same result.

And not because you may leave your variables without (explicitly) assigning some initial values to them: `my @arr` is as good as `my @arr = ()`, and `my $scal` (instead of `my $scal = 'some filler value'`) may actually save you an hour or two one day. Perl is usually (with `use warnings`, yes) good at spotting undefined values in unusual places - but not so lucky with 'filler values'...

The true point of VHLL is that, in my opinion, you can express a solution in Perl code just like in any human language available (and some may be even less suitable for that case).

Don't believe me? Ok, check your code - or rather your set of tasks, for example.

Need to find the lowest element in a array? Or a sum of all values in array? List::Util module is to your command:

```
use List::Util qw( min sum );
my @array_of_values = (1..10);

my $min_value     = min( @array_of_values );
my $sum_of_values = sum( @array_of_values );

say "In the beginning was... @array_of_values";
say "With lowest point at $min_value"; 
say "Collected they give $sum_of_values";
```

Need to construct an array from another array, filtering out unneeded values? grep is here to save the day:

```
@filtered_array = grep { $filter_condition } @source_array;
```

See the pattern? Don't try to code your solution into some machine-codish mumbo-jumbo. ) Find a solution in your own language, then just find means to translate THAT solution into Perl code instead. It's easier than you thought. )

Disclaimer: I do understand that reinventing the wheel may be good for learning why wheels are so useful at first place. ) But I do see how often wheels are reimplemented - becoming uglier and slower in process - in production code, just because people got used to this mode of thinking.